# yii2 login page redirection looping with cancelled status

Tags: php, yii2

After spending so many days, am trying to get some help from experts.
I am stuck with login redirection in my yii2 application only in chrome browser,

[image]

This is my controller class,

```
    class InvitationsController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {   $array=array('index','imageupload','template','category','subcategory','slug','chooseanotherdesign');
        if(!in_array($action->id, $array))
           {
                if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest &&
                    \Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl)
                ) {
                    \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl,FALSE);
                }
           }
                return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
    public function actionGenerateevent(){
        $redirectUrl="";
                if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
                    unset(Yii::$app->session['copyinvitation']);
                    unset(Yii::$app->session['eventform']);
                    Yii::$app->session['eventform']=Yii::$app->request->post();
                }
                if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
                {
                        $eventid=$this->invitation->savecontinue(Yii::$app->session['eventform']);
                        $eventdata=$this->invitation->getEventById($eventid);
                        $refurl=Yii::$app->session['eventform']['refererurl'];
                        $aa['Events']=$eventdata;
                        $aa['refererurl']=$refurl;
                        Yii::$app->session['eventform']=$aa;
                        $redirectUrl = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['invitations/event/'.$eventdata['event_token']]);
                        return $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
                }


    }
}
```

My workflow
step1: submitting formdata to controller xx-action
step2: If user login it will proceed further action
       Else
       am trying to store the values in session then redirecting the page to login

step 3: after successful login am return back to same xx-action

This workflow is working fine in firefox but chrome it's making infinitive loop its not going through the login page. 
Please refer am attached the screenshot

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't infere how are you calling your `actionGenerateevent()` but you seems to have an error there:

```php
$redirectUrl=""; //empty
...
return $this->redirect($redirectUrl); //still empty
```

Since you are not setting your `$redirectUrl`, your `redirect` is redirecting you to the current (same) url again and again, causing the loop.

This is the function used by `redirectUrl()` method: [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail). Its docs says:

> an empty string: the currently requested URL will be returned;

Comment: actually am calling here beforeaction() function so no need that $redirectUrl="".
By the way you are correct, first hit of actionGenerateevent() has the problem, because am submitting form in this action, there is the problem. Now I fixed it. thank you so much.

Comment: @user3535066 I am glad to help! Could you mark my answer, please? thanx